# Error: '-' is not a valid resource name character

Tags: android, android-studio

I have only created an xml file with some textboxes and images. I have only written code in java for adding a date picker. There is no other code.  When I run the project, I get an: "Error: '-' is not a valid resource name character" in the .xml file. What is wrong with the project, and how can I fix the error?

It shows this error:

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
  2.1\7d6c45d59e385ecb07bf4fa7a4a891f9\jetified-car-ui-lib-2.2.1\res\values\values.xml: Error: '-' is not a valid resource name character

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:text="Let's Find Your Doctor"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dentist"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dentist" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/eye"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/eye"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp"/>



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/injection"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/injection"
            android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cardio"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cardio" />


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/simpleSearchView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="270dp"

            android:iconifiedByDefault="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.github.jhonnyx2012.horizontalpicker.HorizontalPicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp" />


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I have only written code for  date  picker in the JAVA:

My java file:

```
public class firstrow extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_firstrow);

        HorizontalPicker picker = (HorizontalPicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);

        picker.setListener(this)
                .setDays(20)
                .setOffset(10)
                .setDateSelectedColor(Color.DKGRAY)
                .setDateSelectedTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                .setMonthAndYearTextColor(Color.DKGRAY)
                .setTodayButtonTextColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setTodayDateTextColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setTodayDateBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
                .setUnselectedDayTextColor(Color.DKGRAY)
                .setDayOfWeekTextColor(Color.DKGRAY)
                .setUnselectedDayTextColor(getColor(R.color.primaryTextColor))
                .showTodayButton(false)
                .init();
        picker.setTodayDateBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        picker.setDate(new DateTime().plusDays(4));

    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSelected(DateTime dateSelected) {

        Toast.makeText(this, dateSelected.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: "I get an: "Error: '-' is not a valid resource name character" in the .xml file.' Please cut and paste the full error message you're getting. Does it give you any line number? Does the text editor show you anything in red? Can you remove stuff from it until the error goes away? That can help you narrow down the exact location.

Comment: what is name of the xml file? do you have image files in resource whose name has "-" ? because android maps file name to a member variable in R which does not allow "-", your file names should not contain "-".

Comment: XML files name is activity_firstrow.xml. I have image files but they don't have "-"

Comment: plz somebody answer

Comment: The error is in this `-car-ui-lib-2.2.1\` library's `values` resource file. Remove it from your  `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @Anjali show me your `strings.xml` file code and screenshots of your `res` folder. Add it to your question.

Comment: The problem is in a values.xml file.  Somewhere you have a value with '-' in its name.  That's an illegal character.  The values must be valid Java variable names-  alphanumeric or underscore, with the first character being a letter or underscore.

Answer (score 1):

check your values.xml file, you have a value name with '-' and this is what's causing the problem.